# How to plot several graphs and make use of the navigation button in [matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib

The latest version of **`matplotlib`** automatically creates navigation buttons under the `graph`. However, the examples I see in the Internet all just show how to create one graph, thus making the button `[Next]` and `[Previous]` useless. How do I plot several graphs and make use of those buttons?

For example I want to make `graph` for `sin()` and `cos()` from `0` degree to `360` degree.

Right now I do it like this:

```
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot

DataRange = range(0, 360)
DataRange = map(scipy.deg2rad, DataRange)
Data1 = map(scipy.sin, DataRange)
Data2 = map(scipy.cos, DataRange)
pyplot.plot(Data1)
pyplot.show()   # <--- if I exclude this
pyplot.plot(Data2)
pyplot.show()
```

The `sin()` graph will be shown. It is when I close the window that the `cos` graph will be shown. If I exclude the first `pyplot.show()`, both will be shown in the same figure.

How to make it so that the second graph is shown when I press the Next button?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/users/navigation_toolbar.html#interactive-navigation), the `Forward` and `Back` buttons are used to allow you to go back to a previous view of a single figure. So for example if you used the  `Zoom-to-rectangle` feature, the `Back` button would return you to the previous display. Depending on your backend, it is possible hook when these buttons are pressed.

You can obviously plot several graphs at the same time using `subplot` as follows:

```
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot

DataRange = range(0, 360)
DataRange = map(scipy.deg2rad, DataRange)
Data1 = map(scipy.sin, DataRange)
Data2 = map(scipy.cos, DataRange)

pyplot.subplot(211)
pyplot.plot(Data1)
pyplot.subplot(212)
pyplot.plot(Data2)
pyplot.show()
```

Giving you:

[image]

Alternatively, you could alternate between your two figures when they are clicked on using the following:

```
import scipy
from matplotlib import pyplot

DataRange = range(0, 360)
DataRange = map(scipy.deg2rad, DataRange)
Data1 = map(scipy.sin, DataRange)
Data2 = map(scipy.cos, DataRange)

toggle = True

def onclick(event):
    global toggle

    toggle = not toggle
    event.canvas.figure.clear()
    
    if toggle:
        event.canvas.figure.gca().plot(Data1)
    else:
        event.canvas.figure.gca().plot(Data2)
    
    event.canvas.draw()

fig = pyplot.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

pyplot.plot(Data1)
pyplot.show()
```

Answer (score 12):

Those prev/next buttons are not for navigating through different plots; they allow the viewer to navigate through the 'views' he has chosen with pan/zoom and zoom-rectangle. In that sense, 'home' is just a shortcut for pressing 'previous' a bunch of times.