# How to setup matplotlib in order to show all figures in one single window?

Tags: python

I want to plot over 100 charts, hence subplots does not work for it. I want to be able to navigate the charts using the arrows in the top side of the Figure window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that `matplotlib` provides such a function that you can choose a specific plot from the plot list, I could not find it in [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/users/event_handling.html). However, by following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33139496/how-to-plot-several-graphs-and-make-use-of-the-navigation-button-in-matplotlib), you can check the plots by clicking. Good luck!

```
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DataRange = range(0, 360)
DataRange = list(map(scipy.deg2rad, DataRange))
Data1 = list(map(scipy.sin, DataRange))
Data2 = list(map(scipy.cos, DataRange))

toggle = True

def onclick(event):
    global toggle

    toggle = not toggle
    event.canvas.figure.clear()

    if toggle:
        event.canvas.figure.gca().plot(Data1)
    else:
        event.canvas.figure.gca().plot(Data2)

    event.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.plot(Data1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Happy to hear that. It would be great if you can accept my answer as the right one.

Comment: Thanks, this will help so I don't have 100 windows for the plots, but I was looking for a way to select the chart I want to review, like a side list where I can pick the chart I want to look at. Do you know if there is a way to do that?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, I didn't see any `matplotlib` method enabling you to select a plot from a plot list. But, what you can do is, you can combine it with an user interface (e.g. pyqt library), where you can choose a plot from the list. You can look into [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QListWidget.html#). If I have time I will do it, but can't promise.